# ifstream проход по строке

Tags: c++, строки, потоки-данных

Просто есть строка string, в ней слова, разделенные пробелами. Как пройтись по этой строке, поочередно занося в буфер эти слова. То есть, сначала в буфер заносим первое слово, потом второе, и так до конца этой строки. Интересует, как сделать это на основе методов string, или другим наиболее рациональным способом.

Comment: `operator>>` не подходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот демонстрационная программа. В качестве "буфера" используется контейнер `std::vector`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    char s[] = "one two three";

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    std::vector<std::string> v;

    std::istringstream is( s );

    std::copy( std::istream_iterator<std::string>( is ),
               std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
               std::back_inserter( v ) );


    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
one two three
one two three
```

Можете заменить объявление символьного массива на объявление объекта типа `std::string`.

```
std::string s( "one two three" );
```